# efficiently merging tables on substrings, not perfect matches

Tags: python, r, string, optimization

I want to merge two tables in R or Python, each with tens of thousands of rows.  However, **I won't be able to merge on perfect matches.**  I'm looking for cases when one key is a substring of another.  The matching substring can contain multiple words.  **I'm looking for a solution that is faster than my brute force code below.**

https://stackoverflow.com/users/170352/brandon-bertelsen gave a nice answer, based toy data I originally suggested.  However, it only matches on single word substrings.  (I hadn't originally made this requirement explicit.)

Here's the code I would use for this situation.

```
library(SPARQL)
library(parallel)
library(Hmisc)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

my.endpoint <- "http://sparql.hegroup.org/sparql/"

go.query <- 'select *
where { graph <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/merged/GO>
{ ?goid
<http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasOBONamespace>
"biological_process"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
?goid rdfs:label ?goterm}}'
go.result <- SPARQL(url = my.endpoint, query = go.query)
go.result.frame <- go.result[[1]]

anat.query <- 'select distinct ?anatterm ?anatid
where { graph <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/merged/UBERON>
{ ?anatid <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasDbXref> ?xr .
?anatid rdfs:label ?anatterm}}'

anat.result <- SPARQL(url = my.endpoint, query = anat.query)
anat.result.frame <- anat.result[[1]]

# slow but recognizes multi-word substrings
loop.solution <-
  mclapply(
    X = sort(anat.result.frame$anatid),
    mc.cores = 7,
    FUN = function(one.anat.id) {
      one.anat.term <-
        anat.result.frame$anatterm[anat.result.frame$anatid == one.anat.id]
      temp <-
        grepl(pattern = paste0('\\b', one.anat.term, '\\b'),
              x = go.result.frame$goterm)
      temp <- go.result.frame[temp , ]
      if (nrow(temp) > 0) {
        temp$anatterm <- one.anat.term
        temp$anatid   <- one.anat.id
        return(temp)
      }
    }
  )

loop.solution <- do.call(rbind, loop.solution)

# from Brandon
# fast, but doesn't recognize multi-word matches
sep.gather.soln <-
  separate(go.result.frame,
           goterm,
           letters,
           sep = " ",
           remove = FALSE) %>%
  gather(goid, goterm) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  setNames(c("goid", "goterm", "code", "anatterm")) %>%
  select(goid, goterm, anatterm) %>%
  left_join(anat.result.frame) %>%
  na.omit()
```

Comment: set( term +' '+ cat for term in terms for cat in set([ dictionary .get(word,'') for word in term.split()]) if cat)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm having trouble figuring where the line breaks and indention would go in this code.

Comment: this is one line code

Comment: Please update your example with real data. I'm not going to install all those packages, so just focus on the data I would need to solve the last part of the problem you are stuck on. Show very clear example input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
  mealtime = c("breakfast","lunch","dinner","dinner"),
  dish = c(
    "cheese omelette",
    "turkey sandwich",
    "bean soup",
    "something very long like this")
)

df2 <- read.table(textConnection(
'ingredient  category
bean        legume
beef        meat
carrot      vegetable
cheese      dairy
milk        dairy
omelette    eggs
sandwich    bread
turkey      meat'), header = TRUE)

df1 <- separate(df1, dish, letters, sep = " ", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  gather(mealtime, dish) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% setNames(c("mealtime","dish","code","ingredient")) %>% 
  select(mealtime, dish, ingredient) %>% 
  left_join(df2) %>% na.omit()

df1
```

`mealtime            dish ingredient category
1 breakfast cheese omelette     cheese    dairy
2     lunch turkey sandwich     turkey     meat
3    dinner       bean soup       bean   legume
5 breakfast cheese omelette   omelette     eggs
6     lunch turkey sandwich   sandwich    bread`

Comment: Thanks, Brandon.  Sorry, my example tables were unclear.  The crux of my problem is that there won't be a perfect match between the join columns, so a standrd merge won't work.

Comment: No, not always two words.  I'm trying to match between different biomedical ontologies.  For example, matching between "inhibition of kidney epithelium development" and "kidney epithelium".  Or between "sudden heart attack" and "heart".

Comment: Changed the approach, melt all possibilities, drop missings, merge, drop missings.

Comment: Wow, looks good.  I'll try it on "real" data soon.  I'll benchmark it against two nested loops and a grepl.

Comment: Sure, you can get some improvements by limiting the "into" field to the maximum word length of your dish. Right now I just jimmy'd it with letters which returns a:z.

Comment: I edited to make one of my requirements more explicit, and to show my code that works but seems inefficient.  Let me know if you have anything to add to nice work you have already suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I am using your original post data.
first split term 
second check the associated item in dictionary
third  combine together

```
terms =["cheese omelette","turkey sandwich","bean soup",]
dictionary ={'turkey': 'meat', 'cheese': 'dairy', 'sandwich': 'bread', 'beef': 'meat', 'omelette': 'eggs', 'bean': 'legume', 'carrot': 'vegetable', 'milk': 'dairy'}

res = set( term +' '+ cat for term in terms for cat in set([ dictionary .get(word,'') for word in term.split()]) if cat) 

for i in res:
    print i


output:
cheese omelette dairy
bean soup legume
turkey sandwich meat
turkey sandwich bread
cheese omelette eggs
```

Comment: Thanks for posting as an answer.  Yes, that works nicely when the key part of the dictionary pairs is a single word.  I wasn't initially clear enough with my requirement that the key could be multiple words, so I updated the question.  Sorry for the moving target.  I am using my loop solution in production now, but I'm still open to suggestions that use multi-word keys.